# Changes doesn't show up on blog

Tags: functions, magento

I am using wordpress in my magento using Fishpig wordpress extension, i have created a functions in functions.php of my theme (though its full integrated, meaning magento theme is applied to blog) but the following function doesn't seem to have any effort. my function is

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'insert_thumbnail_into_feed' );
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'insert_thumbnail_into_feed' );
function insert_thumbnail_into_feed() {
      global $post;
      if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
        // replace thumbnail with yours
        $content = '<p>' .get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) .'</p>';
      }

      // get post content and replace feed content with
      // you can also limit/filter the content to exclude shortcodes and html code etc.
      $content .= '<p>' .get_the_content() .'</p>';

      return $content;
    }
```

is it because feed by default loads the rss and rss doesn't run the mentioned code?
Edit: i am using this [Fishpig](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) extension

Comment: Function by itself doesn't tell us much. How precisely are you using it? You seem to have quite a peculiar setup there.

Comment: @Rarst why is it peculiar? i am using it on rss feed. the function is self explanatory itself

Comment: Because WordPress inside Magento is not exactly typical setup. :) Function shows what it does, you are have not provided info how you are using the function. Which is likely the part where something goes wrong or you wouldn't have the issue with it.

Comment: @Rarst i am using Fishpig magento wordpress integration, i am using it in my wordpress theme function. and when i call feed/ i want it to work.

Comment: What _is_ "fishpig magento integration"? Please link to relevant plugins/themes (?) in your question.

Comment: @Rarst i have edited the question. please see the link

Comment: Is the function called as part of an `add_filter()` or `add_action()`?

Comment: @PatJ i missed the `add_filter`, have a look a code now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Fishpig doesn't use your theme's functions.php file when in the "Fully Integrated" mode, it has a built-in theme that it forces WordPress to use.

You will have to either modify the Fishpig source code and/or ask Fishpig support how you can do this without affecting future upgrades.

Comment: I found a [link](http://www.lotusseedsdesign.com/blog/configure-wordpress-rss-feeds-on-your-magento-store) which tells you how to get what i want,but there is no recent_entries.html i can find. There support haven't replied me yet. any idea on how can i?

Comment: Doesn't look like that article applies to Fishpig, but instead to other WordPress-Magento integration solution. Sorry but you might be better off asking the community at http://magento.stackexchange.com/, since people will probably not know Fishpig here.

Comment: yes,but now i realized i have to make something in magento that can target the feed on wordpress. i don't know what magento uses,functions or what. i would appreciate if i have someone help me with creating function for magento that do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the template files in Magento that are created by the Fishpig extension and that override the WP theme: [Fishpig guide to customising the design and theme of WordPress](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/customising-the-design-and-theme/)

> When WordPress is integrated into Magento with Magento WordPress Integration, the WordPress blog is displayed using your Magento theme and not your WordPress theme. This means that any changes to your WordPress theme (either installing a new theme or modifying your existing WordPress theme) will have no affect on the frontend of your blog. To make changes to the blog, you need to make the changes in your Magento templates.